# Django - making form which contains two related models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I wonder if it is possible to make a Django model based form which will allow to create two models which one will be passed as a foreign key to second one.

let we have these models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    published = models.DateField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'd like to make a view which will contain BookForm and many ChapterForms

Something like:

```
Book.title = [input]
Book.published = [input]
```

and below that (still in the same view)

```
Chapter.name = [input]
Chapter.number = [input]
```

```
Chapter.name = [input]
Chapter.number = [input]
```

```
add more chapters
```

After submitting form, Book and related chapters should be created

How can I achieve it?

Till now I was just making two views:

One for making a Book and second one for chapter which gets created book's id as a parameter in URL, but I'd like to make it in one view to allow user to make Book and Chapters at the same time.

### Edit:

After many tries I made it. I'm not sure if it's proper way to do that but it works fine. (It's made on different models)

That's my code:

```
def Recipe_create_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

    context = {}
    recipe = None

    recipe_form = RecipeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        recipe_form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        if recipe_form.is_valid():
            recipe_form.save()
            recipe = Recipe.objects.create(name=recipe_form.data['name'])
    
    IngredientFormset = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Ingredient, fields=('name', 'quantity'), can_delete=True, extra=3, max_num=10)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = IngredientFormset(request.POST, instance=recipe)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            id = recipe.id
            recipe_duplicate = Recipe.objects.get(id=id-1)
            recipe_duplicate.delete()

            return redirect('index')
    
    formset = IngredientFormset(instance=recipe)

    context['formset'] = formset
    context['recipe_form'] = recipe_form
    return render(request, 'recipes/create_ingredients.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

There should never be a need for a duplicate. I think you don't want:

```
recipe = Recipe.objects.create(name=recipe_form.data['name'])
```

You should be getting the recipe, not creating a new one.

If you do this correctly, you don't need to do anything with the duplicate after `formset.save()`.

Also, `if recipe_form.is_valid():` is false, you need to stop and return an error. You are going on to process ingredients.

Comment: I've did as you said and I'm getting error "save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'recipe'."

Comment: Can you show the new code